# Android: ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity error

Tags: android, runtime-error

I'm working with google maps. When i run my app for the first time it displays a error. I click force close and app runs again and the second time it all good. This is my log cat:

```
08-17 07:06:35.288: ERROR/vold(26): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
08-17 07:06:35.288: ERROR/vold(26): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
08-17 07:06:35.288: ERROR/vold(26): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
08-17 07:06:35.288: ERROR/vold(26): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
08-17 07:06:43.888: ERROR/BatteryService(51): usbOnlinePath not found
08-17 07:06:43.888: ERROR/BatteryService(51): batteryVoltagePath not found
08-17 07:06:43.888: ERROR/BatteryService(51): batteryTemperaturePath not found
08-17 07:06:43.908: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(51): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
08-17 07:06:47.309: ERROR/EventHub(51): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
08-17 07:06:47.309: ERROR/EventHub(51): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
08-17 07:06:47.539: ERROR/System(51): Failure starting core service
08-17 07:06:47.539: ERROR/System(51): java.lang.SecurityException
08-17 07:06:47.539: ERROR/System(51):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
08-17 07:06:47.539: ERROR/System(51):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
08-17 07:06:47.539: ERROR/System(51):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
08-17 07:06:47.539: ERROR/System(51):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:176)
08-17 07:06:47.548: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(51): Crash logging skipped, no checkin service
08-17 07:06:52.005: ERROR/ActivityThread(93): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
08-17 07:06:52.905: ERROR/ActivityThread(93): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
08-17 07:06:52.974: ERROR/ActivityThread(93): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
08-17 07:06:54.728: ERROR/vold(26): Cannot start volume '/sdcard' (volume is not bound)
08-17 07:06:54.934: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(30): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/notification_sound
08-17 07:06:54.944: ERROR/MediaPlayer(51): Unable to to create media player
08-17 07:06:57.375: ERROR/ActivityThread(51): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
08-17 07:06:57.375: ERROR/ActivityThread(51): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
08-17 07:07:00.225: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(207): ERROR: thread attach failed
08-17 07:07:01.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(220): ERROR: thread attach failed
08-17 07:07:07.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(233): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
08-17 07:07:07.805: ERROR/ActivityThread(233): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
08-17 07:07:07.885: ERROR/ActivityThread(233): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
08-17 07:07:08.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.projekat/test.projekat.TrenutnaLokacija}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at test.projekat.TrenutnaLokacija.onCreate(TrenutnaLokacija.java:91)
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     ... 11 more
```

My issue is:

```
08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-17 07:07:08.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at test.projekat.TrenutnaLokacija.onCreate(TrenutnaLokacija.java:90)

firstDot = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude()*1E6),(int) (location.getLongitude()*1E6));
```

I edited question...this is my code...location is null..I started my app on android phone and it doesn't work...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.pocetna);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);     
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);     
        textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(17);      
        mapView.setStreetView(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //mapView.setSatellite(true);       
        sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {                

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                updateWithNewLocation(null);

            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {              
//              TrenutnaLokacija.this.location =  location;
                updateWithNewLocation(location);    

            }
        };

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener);


        try{
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.d("location", "Greska", e);
        }catch (SecurityException s) {
            Log.d("dsds", "Greska", s);
        }

        AlertDialog ad1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        ad1.setTitle("Greska");
        ad1.setMessage("Trenutno nisu ucitane lokacije");
        ad1.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Dozvoli", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface ad, int which) {

            }
        });

        if(location == null){
            ad1.show();
            Intent i = new Intent(TrenutnaLokacija.this, PronadjiKlopuActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }



        GeoPoint firstDot = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude()*1E6),(int) (location.getLongitude()*1E6));

        myPosition = new NewItemizedOverlay(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_pin), firstDot);
        listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.clear();
        listOfOverlays.add(myPosition);
```

Comment: HI, please edit your ques with your onCreate method. actully probleme in your class TrenutnaLokacija.java: in line No. 91 that you can see in error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Null Pointer Exception in the TrenutnaLokacija class on line 91

This is usually when you haven't instantiated a variable yet, or you are retrieving from sharedpreferences or other class call where it returns null if what you specify isn't found.

http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/toptenerrors.html Please see Number 1!

*EDIT*

Because you say it runs fine second time, it sounds like your trying to get a location but it has not loaded yet in your onCreate()

It is possible location is null here:

```
 location.getLatitude();
```

Comment: Line 91 - if i count it, I'm i going to start from onCreate method and I'm i counting and comments that i made???

Comment: To turn line numbers on in eclipse: Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Show line numbers checkbox TICK , apply :)

Comment: My 91 line is empty space... 90 and 92 line are:
firstDot = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude()*1E6),(int) (location.getLongitude()*1E6));
  
  myPosition = new NewItemizedOverlay(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_pin), firstDot);

Comment: You may have changed your code since you showed us the LogCat output, run it again and check.

Comment: it is line 90... my GeoPoint...can you tell me how to fix it??? I'm new in java and android... :)

Comment: it looks like your location object is null as per my edit. Or take a look at this: http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2011/06/how-to-build-location-based-apps-that.html

Comment: Yes..i checked it now...location is null. I will read that blog. I hope it will help me. Thanks again!!! :D